# What are the access rights needed for "Translation Editor" to be able to see their Translation jobs?

Tags: tridion

We're using Tridion 2011 SP1, with SDL WorldServer with Translation Manager and WorkFlow in a typical large blueprint scenario. Editor role has the Translation role with read-write rights (as per the docs). With this role Editors are able to send content to translation. So far so good.

Now once a Translation Job is sent to the WorldServer an editor should be able to see it in the list of Translation Jobs. But in our case Editors can't see anything with above access rights. Now if a System Administrator looks at the Translation Jobs they can see but the editors with Translation read-write rights can't? Is there something else needed?

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For example, if I have a non-admin user called "Editor" belonging to the "Editor" group, I need to  enable the permission on the publication level for "Editor" group to have permission to both translation management and translation configuration.

This step need to be repeated for BOTH source publication and target publication, otherwise Editor will not be able to see the translation jobs

Comment: Earlier had to give access to the parent publication as well to the translation editor else editor was not even able to send the job to TMS for translation. Will try to give access to the parent as well for the translation. Thanks Vin